# Cmake on ARM (arm-none-eabi) - configuration

Tags: windows, make, arm, cmake

I use cmake to compile my project for arm cortex m3 (arm-none-eabi-).

I would like to add the following options:

1.) the linker should generate a .map file of the binary.

2.) make (Unix Makefiles) should store warnings and errors into a seperate file in addition to the stderr /stdout what i currently see.

3.) the config "set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -o myproject.elf" CACHE INTERNAL "")" does not generate my elf, so i manually copy the output to output.elf.

could someone help me here? additionally, if you guys have lots of experience, it would be great if you can give me some hints on what could be done better.
i currently run cmake on windows10 (gnu make, cmake, git bash) and on linux mint.

> compile.sh

```
cmake \
-G "Unix Makefiles" \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
..
make -j8
```

> cmake_arm_none_eabi.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections -o myproject.elf" CACHE INTERNAL "")

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER_ID GNU)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID GNU)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID GNU)

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_FORCED TRUE)
```

> CMakeLists.txt

```
include("cmake_arm_none_eabi.cmake")

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.1)

project(myproject)

ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM)

SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CFLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp")

set(LINKER_SCRIPT "mylinker.ld")

set(CPU_OPTIONS -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3)

SET(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Og -g -DDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-Og -g")

add_compile_options(
    ${CPU_OPTIONS}
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:C>:-std=gnu11> #c11>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-std=gnu++17> #c++17>
    #$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-fms-extensions>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-fno-exceptions>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-fno-rtti>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-fno-use-cxa-atexit>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-fno-threadsafe-statics>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-Wswitch-default>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-Wswitch-enum>
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:-Wmissing-include-dirs>
    -fstrict-volatile-bitfields
    -ffunction-sections
    -fdata-sections
    -fno-threadsafe-statics
    -fdce

    -Wfatal-errors
    -Wall
    -Wextra
    -Wcast-align
    -Wconversion
    -Wsign-conversion
    -Wold-style-cast
    -Wshadow
    -Wlogical-op
    -Wsuggest-override
    -Wsuggest-final-types
    -Wsuggest-final-methods
    -pedantic
)

include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)

link_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    mysource.c
    mysource2.cpp
    ...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CPU_OPTIONS}
    -T${LINKER_SCRIPT}
    -nostartfiles
    m #libm
    gcc #libgcc
)

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY LINK_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${LINKER_SCRIPT})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add linking options with the `-Wl,-Map=$(NAME).map` parameters. Just check out the `\share\gcc-arm-none-eabi\samples\startup` directory of your gcc source folder.